# MySQL delete query doesn't execute

Tags: python, mysql, flask, mysql-python

I want to check for duplicate contacts and remove them from the user's contact list.  There is no error message, it simply doesn't execute.  Why doesn't it work?

```
cmd = "DELETE FROM contacts WHERE contact LIKE '{0}'.format(str(contact_))"
print(cmd)
# DELETE FROM contacts WHERE contact LIKE 'Ilovecake'
cur.execute(cmd)
conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

Comment: DELETE FROM contacts WHERE contact LIKE '%{0}%'.format( str(contact_) )

Answer (score 1):

You are vulerable to SQL injection attacks.  Never format query strings directly, always use parameterized queries.

Your query currently matches contacts that are equal to `contact_`, but your use of `LIKE` implies that you want to match contacts that *contain* that value.  Use wildcards in the query.

```
cur.execute('delete from contacts where contact like ?', ('%{}%'.format(contact_),))
```

The placeholder may be different depending on the dbapi driver you're using.  You can use Flask-SQLAlchemy/SQLAlchemy to normalize parameter substitution as well as manage the connection and session automatically.

Answer (score 0):

if you are doing a kind of search you should use (I GUESS):

```
"DELETE FROM blabla WHERE contact LIKE '%what i am searching%'"
```

which allows text before and after the searched string, apply to your code